# Yielding a List from two lists

Tags: c#, excel, list

I have two lists that hold strings. List a and List b. At the moment i write the values of List a in an excel spreadsheet to column A, and the values of List b into Column. List b should have the same data as List a and be in sequence. This is not always the case.
When i write values of List b in excel, i want to write the value in the cell if it is in list a at the same point, if not i want to write an empty string into the cell.

I have two lists `a = {"a","b","c", "d", "e", "c", "f" }` , and `b = {"a", "d", "e" ,"c"}` . I need to yield a third list c, like from the two `c = { "a", "", "", "d", "e" ,"c", ""}`

Tried:

```
var c = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x.Equals(y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? x : "");
```

But that would only give me `c = {"a"}`

Comment: What is the logic behind?

Comment: You also need to format your question and show us what you tried :)

Comment: these are string list.. List<String> right ?

Comment: Does the position matter?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad The logic is roughly: Compare a and b stepwise. If there's an element in a that is "missing" in b, "fill in" a blank string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following method:

```
IEnumerable<T> FillBlanks<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> collection, T blank)
{
    // TODO error checking
    using(var e = collection.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool more = e.MoveNext();
        foreach(var x in source)
            if(more && x.Equals(e.Current))
            {
                yield return x;
                more = e.MoveNext();
            }
            else
                yield return blank;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var a = new [] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "f" };
var b = new [] {"a", "d", "e" ,"c"};
var c = FillBlanks(a, b, "");
```

`c` is now:

[image]

Comment: @svick True. Removed the useless cast. Better to create an overload that accepts and uses an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

If the index matters:

```
var c = a.Select((s, i) => b.ElementAtOrDefault(i) == s ? s : "").ToList();
```

otherwise:

```
var c = a.Select(s => b.Contains(s) ? s : "").ToList();
```

if the case doesn't matter:

```
var c = a.Select(s => b.Contains(s, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? s : "")
         .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think it returns proper results.

Comment: Kudos for such an elegant sol. Good one tim

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Now tested, yes, it does not yield the desired result(only `a`). However, i must admit that i yet don't understand the logic.

Comment: The logic is roughly: Compare `a` and `b` stepwise. If there's an element in `a` that is "missing" in `b`, "fill in" a blank string.

Comment: Here b is subset of a, what if b has more element and a has less, this will not work then

Comment: a is the list to what b must conform to. If b does have more, those that are not in a must be dropped. which apparently is what is happening as far as i can tell.